# Ghost Fields in Abelian and Non-Abelian gauge theories

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-theory, yang-mills, gauge, ghosts

I have some questions about ghost fields in QED and in a non Abelian gauge theory:

1. Does the fact that ghosts and photons are decoupled depend on the choice of the gauge-fixing function? In the Lorenz and Coulomb gauge this happens and this make me think that it could be a deep consequence of the "abelianity" of QED. In particular, my idea is that, under a gauge transformation, the gauge field doesn't acquire a term with the gauge field itself (the structure  constants are zero): so, when we do the exponentiation of the Faddeev-Popov determinant, we have only a kinetic term in the ghost action and its contribution can be integrated out.
2. In non Abelian gauge theories we can choice the axial gauge, which is not covariant. In this gauge however ghosts and gauge fields are decoupled.  So, why don't we always choose the axial gauge in such a way that we can forget about ghosts?